# How to communicate between a libwebsockets client and a websocket server like Nginx?

Tags: nginx, websocket, network-programming, protocols, libwebsockets

I try to implement a websocket client (with *libwebsockets* in C and it's not an option). As example, i used the *[test-client.c](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/v2.2-stable/test-server/test-client.c)* given with the library. 
My websocket-client actualy works fine with the *test-server.c* . But i experienced some complications to communicate with an *nginx* server.

As i understand, the handshack doesn't end up well because *nginx* doesn't know my **websocket client's sub-protocol**. 
Well, it appears, like in *test-client.c* i'm implementing my own sub-protocol (with its own name, its own callback function).

My questions are :

- **Is there a way to not use a specific websocket sub-protocol with *libwebsockets* ?**
- **If not, am i supposed to implement an existing one (client side) like *WAMP* or something in this [list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xml#subprotocol-name)?** (I do not want to reinvent the wheel...)
- **If not, does it exist a "default" websocket subprotocol that i can specify to nginx and in which it could be compatible with my websocket-client ?** (I'm only doing some simple send/receive action with my client. Implementing a libwebsockets client seems completly useless if it can only communicate with a libwebsockets server)
- **Are my questions relevant? If not why ? What am i missing ?**

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with Andy, the libwebsockets designer (https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/issues/834), the simpliest way to make it works is to not named the sub-protocol in the structure defining the websocket sub-protocol client's side :

```
/* list of supported sub-protocols and callbacks */
static struct lws_protocols ws_protocols[] = {
        { NULL, ws_callback, 0, 128, },
        { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 } /* end */
};
```

Libwebsockets client doesn't try to negociate with `sec-websocket-protocol` in the header, the handshake works just fine with nginx.